# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'AnyObject?' with no arguments

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, anyobject

I am using swift 3 to build a type of chat messenger.
To store loggedIn Users, I try to use an onject of type AnyObject.

```
    var loggedInUser = AnyObject?()
```

And it gives the following error: 
ViewController.swift:29:24: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'AnyObject?' with no arguments

Comment: What is the purpose of using the quite unspecified type `AnyObject` instead of a more specific type `User` or what type you are using for the user. Does `AnyObject` have initializers at all?

Comment: were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happened to the UIView?() constructor in Swift 3.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549717/what-happened-to-the-uiview-constructor-in-swift-3-0)