# What happened to the UIView?() constructor in Swift 3.0?

Tags: swift, option-type, swift3

In Swift 2.2, I often declared variables using a concise syntax similar to `let x = UIView?()`. This gave `x` the `UIView?` type, and initialised it with `nil`. *(Of course, you could use any type instead of `UIView` in these examples)*

However, when I do the same in Swift 3.0, I get an error:
`Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UIView?' with no arguments`. It also says that `Overloads for 'UIView?' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (Wrapped), (nilLiteral: ())`. Somehow, I don't think `UIView?(nilLiteral: ())` is quite what I'm after.

Naturally, there are other alternative methods to do the same thing, such as `let x: UIView? = nil` and `let x = nil as UIView()`, but they're more verbose than the method I was using previously. Was the `UIView?()` constructor removed in Swift 3.0, or has it been replaced in a form that I've not yet discovered?

Comment: use the correct way, that is `var x: UIView? = nil` or just `var x: UIView?`. Don't try to think up alternative syntax.

Comment: While I understand that your so-called "correct way" works too, the alternative syntax worked fine in prior versions of Swift, and I'd prefer to use that as I have done so previously.

Comment: The problem with `let x = UIView?()` is that it looks so very similar to `let x = UIView()`, but does something *completely* different. You *could* add an extension to `Optional` to add an `init()` back, but I would strongly advise against it.

Comment: Try to accept that what you were "often doing" was wrong and you can no longer do it that way, and move on.

Comment: The `?` is what makes the variable optional, it is automatically set to `nil`, anything else is unnecessary.

Comment: @Hamish: Alright, thanks. If that constructor was removed from Swift 3 for that reason, that's fine by me, and would be the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @matt, I understand that things change and move on (especially in a new language like Swift!), but there's no need to slander me for being "wrong" without any reasoning behind it.

Comment: @ben I'm fairly new to swift, so I have never seen `UIView?()`  used, do you know if it was meant work differently? I can't find anything on it, I'd happily clarify my answer, if I can find why it no longer works.

Comment: @Sarcoma The syntax `UIView?` is just syntactic sugar for `Optional<UIView>`, therefore `UIView?()` is just syntactic sugar for `Optional<UIView>.init()`. In Swift 2, `Optional`'s [`init()`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/Optional/#init) constructs a new optional value set to `.None`. So yes, it was working correctly. In Swift 3 however, this initialiser has been removed, which is why `UIView?()` no longer works.

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for that. You should post this as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following does initialise x to nil, the brackets are entirely superfluous.

```
var x: UIView?
return x == nil
```

Will return true

Check out the developer docs for more information.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content//documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

> If you define an optional variable without providing a default value,
>   the variable is automatically set to nil for you:

```
var surveyAnswer: String?
// surveyAnswer is automatically set to nil
```

@Hamish posted a comment to clarify the reason why UIView?() no longer works:

*“The syntax UIView? is just syntactic sugar for Optional, therefore UIView?() is just syntactic sugar for Optional.init(). In Swift 2, Optional's init() constructs a new optional value set to .None. So yes, it was working correctly. In Swift 3 however, this initialiser has been removed, which is why UIView?() no longer works”*

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction – it's easy to skip over the introductory chapter! Your first example should say `let x: UIView?` according to the documentation, BTW ;) Other than that, though, that syntax is a good replacement, thanks!

Comment: Ha yeah, totally needs to be a var! I usually just double click the exclamation mark to fix that one :)

Comment: Ah, no. Whether it's a var or a let, it should use `:` instead of `=`, and let it use the default value of `nil` (as in the example you copied from the docs).