# Cannot invoke initializer for type ? with no arguments

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm trying to migrate an app on swift3 but i'm facing one major problem.
When i'm trying to initialize custom classes like this:

```
var news = News?()
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type "News?" with no arguments.

I tried to add the following convenience init but still got the error:

```
convenience init() {
    self.init(response: HTTPURLResponse(), representation: "" as AnyObject)
}
```

main init func:

```
@objc required init(response: HTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject)
```

Comment: If there are initializers with arguments you have to call them. It is required that all (non-optional) stored properties must have an initial value. By the way: why do you want to initialize an optional instance although you have only non-failable initializers?

Comment: See [What happened to the UIView?() constructor in Swift 3.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549717/what-happened-to-the-uiview-constructor-in-swift-3-0) – in Swift 3 `Optional`'s `init()` has been removed, simply do `var news : News?` instead.