# Cannot invoke initializer for type with no arguments

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols, swift3

Just upgraded to Swift 3, and I'm getting an error in my code that I can't seem to fix.

```
    protocol getSearchDelegate {
    func resultsReady()
}

class GetSearch: NSObject {

    var delegate = getSearchDelegate?() //ERROR: cannot invoke initializer for type 'getSearchDelegate?' with no arguments.
```

This code worked in Swift 2, but when upgrading to Swift 3, it shows the error.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So just write `var delegate : getSearchDelegate?`. As a side note, type names should be `UpperCamelCase` as per the Swift API design guidelines.

Comment: That worked, thanks!  Any idea why 'var delegate = getSearchDelegate?()' doesn't work anymore?

Comment: Take a look at the linked Q&A, specifically [my comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549717/what-happened-to-the-uiview-constructor-in-swift-3-0#comment66411789_39549717) which explains why it no longer works.