# Cannot invoke initializer for type AnyObject? with no arguments

Tags: swift

I created a variable in my Xcode project.

```
var user = AnyObject?()
```

This line of code came back as an error. The error message said

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'AnyObject?' with no arguments

Why do I receive this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: `AnyObject` is a protocol. You can't create an instance of an `AnyObject`.

Comment: @rmaddy But `AnyObject?` *is* a concrete type (namely `Optional<AnyObject>`), which you can create an instance of ;) (Just no longer by using `init()` as the OP is trying to do here)

Comment: `var user = AnyObject?.self as Any`...

Answer (score 0):

What you've written is the equivalent of:

```
var user = Optional<AnyObject>.init()
```

But [`Optional`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optional) doesn't have an `init()` initializer. What are you trying to do?

Comment: In Swift 2, `Optional` did have an `init()`, which created a new instance set to `.None` – however in Swift 3 this initialiser has been removed. The equivalent is simply `var user : AnyObject?` – although this is all [covered in the dupe Q&A I proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549717/what-happened-to-the-uiview-constructor-in-swift-3-0).

Answer (score 0):

If you really are trying to define a variable of type `AnyObject?` and you want to put an *empty* `Optional<AnyObject>` inside it you can simply write

```
var user: AnyObject? = .none
```

or as suggested by @Hamish

```
var user: AnyObject?
```

Comment: (Mutable) optionals by default have a value of `.none` :)