# why do i keep getting “AnyObject cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers”

Tags: swift, anyobject

I have been following a tutorial on youtube and been coding a twitter like app in xcode and keep returning this error, the tutorial was using an earlier version of swift. How do i move past this?

```
class HandleViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var fullName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var handle: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var startTweeting: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var errorMessage: UILabel!

    var user = AnyObject()
    var rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    }
```

Comment: Probably a dupe of [What happened to the UIView?() constructor in Swift 3.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39549717/2976878)

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that error because `AnyObject` in Swift is a [Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html), not a class, structure, or enum. A protocol is sort of a blueprint for a class, and you create classes that conform to it, but the protocol itself can never be instantiated.

As for how to fix it: It looks like the tutorial you're following uses the same code as the tutorial [here](https://github.com/nathvarun/Twitter-Clone-Swift-IOS-Firebase-Tut-2-SENDING-TWEETS/blob/master/Twitter%20Clone/HandleViewController.swift). It assigns a value to `user` in `viewDidLoad`, and treats it as an optional after that. So the initial value is just a placeholder that's never getting used.

You can change the declaration to an optional instead, giving it a type but no value:

```
var user: AnyObject?
```

---

`AnyObject` has *always* been a `Protocol` in Swift, so there could *never* be an instance of it. So why did it work in the previous version of Swift used in the tutorial? Well for one, it looks like there's a typo in your version. In the tutorial it looks like this:

```
var user = AnyObject?()
```

The question mark after `AnyObject?` makes it an `Optional` of type `AnyObject`. In Swift prior to 3.0, `Optional` had an `init()` method that would create an empty instance. So `AnyObject?()` was shorthand for a new `Optional` of type `AnyObject`, value set to nil. In Swift 3 the superfluous initializer was dropped, so that shorthand no longer works. But just declaring the variable as an optional has the same effect.